# Size of struct node in C

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, structure, sizeof

I know there is a mistake in my cod because I didn't allocate any memory. But I'm curious to know why sizeof(struct node) shows 16 in my computer although I haven't allocated memory yet.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct node));

    return 0;
}
```

`

I thought a size zero would return but It didn't happend. Can you explain why sizeof(struct node) retuns 16?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you're working in C or C++, but `sizeof` semantics are similar in this case, regardless.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof is a good place to start.

`sizeof(type)` returns the size in bytes of the object representation of `type`.

It tells you how much memory you will need to allocate for one of those things. The information (the size of the type) is known at compile time, so there's no reason you can't get it without actually allocating memory.

And in fact if you were to allocate memory with `malloc`:

`myNode = malloc(sizeof (struct node))`

In that line of code, `sizeof(struct node)` is being calculated *before* memory is allocated. It's calculated at compile time, so that the code generated is essentially `malloc(16)`.